# Why activate chart first?

Tags: vba, excel

Don't know if it is the best title for my question... :)

I have a chart in excel. I want to use SetElement.

If i use this code it gets an error (Object doesn't support this property or method):

```
Dim Graphics As Worksheet
Set Graphics = Worksheets("Graph")
Graphics.ChartObjects("Chart 1").SetElement (msoElementChartTitleNone)
```

If i use this code it works well:

```
Dim Graphics As Worksheet
Set Graphics = Worksheets("Graph")
Graphics.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleNone)
```

Can someone explain why the first option isn't working?
It is still the same command on the same object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same command (method) on a different object (ChartObject vs Chart).

Try:

```
Graphics.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SetElement ...
```

Comment: Thanks that works, on somehow i knew it should be that simple :)